# AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular5

I am trying to send a post request to receive my access token from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`. When I tried this in my REST client, it works, but when I try to integrate it to my app, it sends me a error `400 Bad Gateway`, with the message `AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'`. I tried searching for answers, and found out that I need to implement headers in my post request, so I did that, but it still won't work. Any ideas?

Http Imports:
`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';`

Call to post request:

```
var url=this.outlook_authentification_endpoint+"token";
var query_parameters=JSON.stringify({grant_type:"authorization_code", client_id:this.outlook_client_id, code: this.outlook_user_code, client_secret: this.outlook_secret_key, redirect_uri: this.outlook_redirect_uri});
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};
this.query_service.postOutlook(url, query_parameters, httpOptions, (data)=>
{   
  console.log(data);
});
```

Call to the post function:

```
public postOutlook(url, query, headers, callback)
  {
    this.operation_pending=true;
    this.http_client.post(url,query, headers).subscribe((data)=>
    {
      this.operation_pending=false;
      callback(data);
    });
  }
```

Can anyone see where my error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong OAuth2 flow (the way of getting tokens). You are using the [Auth code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), which cannot be used in browser applications, because you would have to keep your client secret in JavaScript, which means make it public. So you cannot access the `/token` endpoint either.

You should use the [Implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), which is designed for browser applications. Then you get tokens right into your Angular application without the need of going to the `/token` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought about that but it seems that I cannot receive my refresh_token when doing it that way.

Comment: You don't need a refresh token in a browser application - just call the `/auth` endpoint with [`prompt=none` query param](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) in a hidden iframe to get a new access/ID token before the old one expires. If you really need a refresh token, you must get it from the backend (in exchange for an auth code).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out.